# Will Bluemix OpenWhisk be available on other regions

Tags: ibm-cloud, openwhisk

At this moment I see the OpenWhisk for Bluemix availabe only on US South region. Will this service available in other (EU - UK/D) regions? I am unable to find any information / planning (I don't think it is effective to move data forth and back across half of the globe for each request)

Comment: This type of question is not appropriate for Stack Overflow as it is not a technical question. In the future, please use dW Answers for non-technical questions: https://developer.ibm.com/answers/smartspace/bluemix/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, our intention is to be in Europe in the near future. pls feel free to DM me on Twitter (@michael_beh) if you'd like to discuss details.

Comment: However, please note that it is IBM policy not to discuss future plans publicly as plans change and we cannot commit to having a service in a specific region before it is officially announced.

Comment: @BillWentworth: roger wilco. next time I will ask dW first. I understand you have strict communication policies, but -  keep cool man :)   (be happy people are interested )

Comment: Understood. :-) We just don't want to commit to deliver something and then have our customers disappointed if it does not happen due to a variety of reasons.